# C# Generated Excel File: File Format or File Extension is not valid

Tags: c#, excel, syncfusion

I'm calling the action "Export" where i pass a list of viewmodels and define the format

```
public ActionResult DownloadTokenlist(string startDate = null, string endDate = null)
            {        
                using (HRCTSStatisticDb db = new HRCTSStatisticDb(Setting.ClientId))
                {    
                    List<TokenExportViewModel> tokenExportViewModels = new List<TokenExportViewModel>();

                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename=Tokenlist_{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.xlsx");
                    log.InfoFormat($"The {new HomeController().UserRole(Context.LoggedInUser)}: {Context.LoggedInUser} has used the exceldownload");

                    return File(new ExcelExport().Export(tokenExportViewModels), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                }
            }
```

The action i call (ExcelEngine is by Syncfusion):

```
public MemoryStream Export(List<TokenExportViewModel> list)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (ExcelEngine excelEngine = new ExcelEngine())
        {
            IApplication application = excelEngine.Excel;
            application.DefaultVersion = ExcelVersion.Excel2010;
            IWorkbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);
            IWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Create("Tokenlist");

            IStyle defaultStyle = workbook.Styles.Add("default");
            defaultStyle.Font.Size = 12;

            worksheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(1, 20, defaultStyle);
            worksheet.SetDefaultRowStyle(1, 300, defaultStyle);

            worksheet.UsedRange.AutofitColumns();
            worksheet.Range["A1"].Text = $"Tokenlist - {DateTime.Today.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}";
            worksheet.Range["A1"].CellStyle = h1Style;
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            workbook.Close();
        }
        return stream;
    }
```

I only posted the code which has an impact on the file and (maybe) could create the error. 
There is no error, until i open the file, then this exception pops up:

> Excel cannot open the file 'Tokenlist_22.05.2018.xlsx' because the
>   file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has
>   not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of
>   the file.

I've tried to change the file format to .xls and .vbs but neither works. With .xls I can open the document but then it has no data in it.

The .close() doesn't change much, it just closes the output stream previously opened.

Comment: If you save the workbook server end, and client end what differences are there?

Comment: Try renaming the extension to xls. If that doesn't work, output to a csv and check the data in the sheet.

Comment: You're trying to `Save` a `Workbook` through a `MemoryStream` object, just to be clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the FileContentResult [Overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470835(v=vs.108).aspx) where you can provide the`fileDownloadName` like this:

```
return File(excelExport.Export(tokenExportViewModels).ToArray(),"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", $"Tokenlist_{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")}.xlsx");
```

And use the stream [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IO.MemoryStream.ToArray);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) extension to return a `byte[]`.

(I assume your `Export` method is generating a valid document)

Answer (score 2):

As stream reached end position while returning it, the downloaded file is getting corrupted. So, it is recommended to set its current position to 0 to resolve this issue. Please refer below code to achieve the same.

Code Example:

```
            workbook.SaveAs(stream);
            workbook.Close();
            stream.Position = 0;
```

We have also shared a simple sample for your reference which can be downloaded from following link.

Sample Link: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Sample1020485770.zip

I work for Syncfusion.